# Change existing CSS with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div's on top of each other, and by clicking a button want to change the z-index to 100 with a function. Sounds easy, hundreds of examples, but it doesn't work. One thing all the examples had in common was that there was no existing CSS code before the function was implemented, might that be the problem?

Button:

```
<button type="button" id="trailerButton" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="margin-top: 20px;">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Choose a trailer
</button>
```

Script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#trailerButton").click(function () {
          $("#chooseTrailer").css("z-index", "100");
       });
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Add your code instead image.

Comment: link:-http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Comment: @Raziasultana I added that snippet into a function and also tried putting it in the button "onclick" still nothing...

Answer (score 1):

For z-index to work, add `position: relative` or `position: absolute` to css of that element.
Or using jquery

```
$('#trailerButton').click(function() {
    $('#chooseTrailer').css('z-index', '100');
    $('#chooseTrailer').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
});
```

Comment: Why placing single css statement in `{}` brackets?

Comment: Sorry, edited my post now for better reading. The position was already relative and still not working. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to answer above:

```
$('#trailerButton').click(function() {
    $('#chooseTrailer').css({
              'position':'relative',
              'z-index':'999999'});
});
```

You can do it by putting everything in `{}` brackets with `:` object notation.

Alternatively, you can try with `cssText` to set `!important` but that will overwrite all other CSS for that element:

```
$('#trailerButton').click(function() {
        $('#chooseTrailer').css({'cssText', 'z-index: 999999 !important'});
```